# Skills to solve KKT condition equations.

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

The problem is
$$\begin{aligned}
\min ~&\frac{1}{2}\|x\|_2^2\\
\text{s.t.}~ &a^Tx=b\\
&x\ge 0
\end{aligned}$$
How can we find the optimal solution with KKT condition?

### My thinking:

Firstly, it's trival to write the KKT condition as follows:
$$L(x,w,v)=\frac{1}{2}\|x\|_2^2+w(a^Tx-b)-v^Tx$$
$$\begin{aligned}
\nabla_x L(x,w,v)=x+wa-v&=0\\
v&\ge 0\\
a^Tx&=b\\
x&\ge 0\\
v_ix_i&=0
\end{aligned}$$
But how can we solve $x$ with expression of $a,b$? Could anyone help to give the detailed steps? Thanks.

Comment: You can start with $v\geq 0$, $x \geq 0$ and $v^Tx=0$.

Comment: @LinAlg Could please show me how to solve this?

Comment: What can you say about $v_i$ when $x_i>0$?

Comment: The problem might be infeasible. E.g. $a=1$ and $b=-1$